# Stripe does not pass stripeToken to Django backend

Tags: javascript, django, stripe-payments

I am building a Django application with stripe integration. I would like to use the charges api in order to have individuals make donations through the website. Currently I have copy/pasted most of the charges api code from the documentation and stripe elements pages. However, the javascript included under the python tab does not send the stripeToken needed to create a customer and charge the card. I have printed the information at the specific url, but the stripeToken key does not even seem to be generated as it does not even return an empty form part. The rest of the default javascript seems to work fine, but the submit function, or the stripeTokenHandler does not seem to function at all. I have tried adding in a hidden input for the field and switching the handler to ajax and both these methods were unsuccessful. Is there something I am missing?

Django HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'Charge' %}" method="post" id="payment-form">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <div class="input-section">
          <label>Name on Card:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="enter name..." />
        </div>

      <div class="donation-input">
        <div class="input-section">
          <label>Donation Amount:</label>
          <div style="display: flex;">
            $<input id="amount" type="text" name="amount" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="card-element" style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;">
          Credit or debit card
        </label>
        <div id="card-element">
        </div>

        <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
      </div>

      <img style="display: block; margin: 10px 0;" width="300" height="94" src="{% static 'securetransaction.png' %}" alt="Stripe secure transaction">

      <button type="submit" class="form-button">Submit Payment</button>
    </form>
```

Stripe JS:

```
    var stripe = Stripe('/*public test key here*/');

    // Create an instance of Elements.
    var elements = stripe.elements();

    var style = {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4'
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
      }
    };

    // Create an instance of the card Element.
    var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
    card.mount('#card-element');

    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
    card.on('change', function(event) {
      var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
      } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
      }
    });

    // Handle form submission.
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
          // Inform the user if there was an error.
          var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
          errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
          console.log(result.token)
          // Send the token to your server.
          stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        }
      });
    });

    // Submit the form with the token ID.
    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
      console.log('Submit Form')
      // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
      var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

      // Submit the form
      form.submit();
    }
```

and Django view:

```
def charge(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST) // Does not print any stripeToken

        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            name = request.POST['name'],
            source = request.POST['stripeToken'] // Causes error due to missing token
        )

        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            customer = customer,
            amount = (request.POST['amount'] * 100),
            currency= 'usd',
            description = 'Donation'
        )

    return render(request, 'thankyou.html')
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?  That would likely cause this behavior.

Comment: There are no errors, I have tried switching the method the ajax, wrapping it in a function and calling it from the onsubmit form attribute, and contacting stripe support, so far no progress.

Comment: As an update I contacted stripe tech support. I informed them that this is an issue affecting multiple people using Django as their server side framework. They assured me they are looking for a solution.